# Est-ce que « classes dominantes », « hauts dirigeants », « figure d’autorité » et « hautes classes sociales » conviendraient dans le contexte?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

**Les classes dominantes**, depuis des siècles, nous {*font accroire*} et cherche à nous convaincre que les voleurs sont majoritairement des pauvres issus des bas-fonds, mais il n’en est rien. Il serait temps d’{*inverser les rôles*}, le riche devient le méchant, le pauvre, le gentil qui tente de survivre, de {*retourner les accusations contre*} **les hauts dirigeants**, souvent les plus riches, ceux qui font **figure d’autorité**, qui ont tendance à répandre de fausses croyances à leur profit, qui usent de procédés malhonnêtes sous des dehors avenants car oui, il faut le dire, ils manipulent toutes les sphères de la société pour s’enrichir aux dépens d’autrui, que ce soit en sous-payant les pauvres travailleurs, qui finiront par avoir de la difficulté à joindre les deux bouts ou en {*maquillant*}leurs pratiques malhonnêtes et parfois illégales en procédés qui se parent de toutes les vertus et qui auront pour conséquence de faire pâtir une fois de plus les pauvres contribuables, notamment en les faisant payer plus d’impôts et plus de taxes ou par des politiques d’austérité qui auront un effet néfaste sur les plus vulnérables. Les vrais voleurs viennent des **hautes classes sociales**, non l’inverse.

Je souhaiterais savoir comment vous auriez exprimé ce paragraphe dans vos propres mots ou si vous auriez remanié quelques passages. (Je n’ai pas tourné et retourné dans ma tête tout ce que j’ai écrit, j’ai juste couché par écrit ce qui me venait spontanément à l’esprit, aussi embrouillées, farfelues, incohérentes ou contradictoires que puissent paraître les idées.) Aussi j’aimerais qu’on me présente des synonymes de termes ou d’expressions que j’ai employés dans le texte en question, comme « faire accroire », « inverser les rôles », « retourner les accusations contre » et « maquiller ». Ce que je cherche avant toute chose à perfectionner, c’est la forme; le fond est ici secondaire ou facultatif mais les commentaires sont les bienvenus.

Comment: Je dirais "classes aisées" plutôt que "hautes classes sociales"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tous les termes en question sont, d'après mon jugement, bien choisis (« classes aisées » est une possibilité de remplacement pour « hautes classes sociales » (on trouve ce terme vieux depuis quelques temps, ou on n'a plus tant besoin du concept qu'il signifie, et il est comparativement beaucoup moins courant).

[image]

[image]

*Détails variés*

Qu'est-ce que ce fond ? La forme est indissossiable du fond, c'est à dire le signifié. Si on ignore ce « fond » et si on prétend que seule la forme compte, tout devient légitime dans n'importe quelle forme grammaticalement et sémantiquement correcte, et on ne la questionne plus. Il n'y a donc de dicussion possible de la forme du point de vue sémantique que si l'on discute conjointement le signifié, c'est à dire la réalité qu'elle est sensée représenter.

1/ **{font accroire}** Le terme « faire accroire » me parait trop pragmatique, et je lui préfèrerais quelque chose come « *laisser entendre* », qui implique une notion de distance, que je trouve nécessaire. Les classes dominantes n'entrent pas en lisse en tant que championnes de la juste répartition de la richesse contre le pauvre qu'elles traiteraient en mécréant ; elles ont une attitude plus subtile.

2/ **{inverser les rôles}** Il n'est pas du tout question, strictement, d'une inversion des « rôles », comme par exemple de considérer que dorénavant seulement le riche —en minorité— serait exploité par le pauvre. Un autre terme est souhaitable, peut-être un terme comme « *faire la part de ce qui revient aux uns et aux autres* ».

3/ **{retourner les accusations contre}** Les accusations ne sont pas réelles, certains dans les hautes couches d'une société, et dans certains contextes historiques, peuvent les sous-entendre, mais ces individus passent, dans l'ensemble, inaperçus ; encore une fois, ces termes ne sont pas représentatifs de la réalité, qui est toute autre. Les classes possédantes peuvent laisser entendre que les déshérités de la fortune sont trop exigeants, mais elles se gardent bien de les culpabiliser.

4/ **{maquillage}** Ce mot, bien qu'accepté par les dictionnaires comme du vocabulaire courant, n'a pas le vernis que ceux-ci lui prétendent implicitement ;  à mon avis, c'est familier, voire très familier. Je le remplacerais donc par « travestissant ».

5/ *pauvres travailleurs*      Je n'utiliserais pas le terme « pauvres travailleurs », qui a des connotations sentimentales, et j'en resterais à la simple caractérisation que permet « *travailleurs pauvres* » ; il en va de même pour « pauvre contribuables ». Cela semble plus approprié, vu le ton analytique que laisse supposer ce texte en général, mais on peut, à la rigueur, tolérer l'alliance de ces deux tons ; cependant, ils semblent assez incompatibles.

6/ *finiront par avoir de la difficulté à joindre les deux bouts*      La situation qui est impliquée par ces termes n'est  qu'un détail dans le processus qui laisserait le pauvre dans le besoin, et donc elle n'est pas la référence qui convient (*qui sont perpétuellement dans le besoin*). De plus, « joindre les deux bouts », quoi qu'en disent les dictionnaires (courant), n'est que du vocabulaire familier.

7/ *qui se parent de toutes les vertus et qui auront pour conséquence de faire pâtir une fois de plus les pauvres contribuables*      La voix active non pronominale convient mieux : « *qu'ils parent de toutes les vertus* ». Le présent convient mieux : « *et qui ont pour conséquence* ».  Un présentatif a plus de force ici : « *qu'une fois de plus ce sont les contribuables pauvres qui en pâtissent* ». (*qu'ils parent de toutes les vertus et qui ont pour conséquence qu'une fois de plus  ce sont les contribuables pauvres qui en pâtissent* »)

La tâche de mettre tout ça bout à bout est laissée au lecteur. D'autre options, peut-être plus heureuses encore,  pourront   peut-être ainsi lui venir à l'esprit.